# How do I restart a web server used by WordPress running on AWS EC2

Tags: reboot, webserver, amazon-ec2, wordpress

I have inherited ownership of an AWS EC2 instance running WordPress.
I am unfamiliar with Unix.
I do not know how WordPress was installed.
I do not know how to check what web server is running.
WordPress is telling me I should upgrade to a new version of PHP.
I have not been able to connect to the AWS EC2 instance with an RSA key (a different issue) so instead have been logging into AWS and am using Amazon Cloudshell.

I have followed a set of steps to enable PHP version 8.2 which I think has worked as:

sudo amazon-linux-extras | grep php

_  php8.0                   available    [ =stable ]

_  php8.1                   available    [ =stable ]

68  php8.2=latest            enabled      [ =stable ]

WordPress tells me the site is running PHP 7.0.30 and I expected to see that version in the php list but it didn't appear.

After enabling php8.2, WordPress still flags that I should upgrade to a new version of PHP. The last step in the instructions I've been following is to "Restart your Webserver". I have tried the command to do this but it did not work:

sudo systemctl restart httpd

Failed to get D-Bus connection: Operation not permitted

which httpd

/usr/bin/which: no httpd in (/usr/local/sbin:/usr/local/bin:/usr/sbin:/usr/bin:/sbin:/bin:/usr/lib/node_modules/aws-cdk/bin:/home/cloudshell-user/.local/bin:/home/cloudshell-user/bin)

What do I need to do to restart my web server?

Comment: Are you sure the server is running Ubuntu? The Apache web server is not called `httpd` on Ubuntu-based servers 

Comment: Thank you. I got an email from Amazon yesterday telling me I am running Ubuntu 18.04 LTS and its time to upgrade, so pretty certain I am running Ubuntu.  I saw something that suggested I use sudo systemctl restart apache2 for Ubuntu, but got the same D-Bus message.

Comment: I've just managed to figure out how to get my RSA key working properly and was able to connect to the AWS server. I discovered the installation is bitnami  and the command to restart the web server is: sudo /opt/bitnami/ctlscript.sh restart apache. Sadly I've now discovered that all the php updating I've done before this doesn't affect bitnami installs and it looks like updating php involves starting a new server and migrating stuff to it.  Anyways, I've answered my own question.